# How to convert uint8_t[][] to char[] in cpp

Tags: c++

I have to convert the number generated by uint8_t[][] to simple char[]. How can I convert uint8_t[][] number to char key[]. I have convert number to char and want to store to the database.

```
static const uint8_t blake2s_kat[BLAKE2_KAT_LENGTH][BLAKE2_KAT_LENGTH] = 
{
{
    0x69, 0x21, 0x7A, 0x30, 0x79, 0x90, 0x80, 0x94,
    0xE1, 0x11, 0x21, 0xD0, 0x42, 0x35, 0x4A, 0x7C,
    0x1F, 0x55, 0xB6, 0x48, 0x2C, 0xA1, 0xA5, 0x1E,
    0x1B, 0x25, 0x0D, 0xFD, 0x1E, 0xD0, 0xEE, 0xF9
},
{
    0xE3, 0x4D, 0x74, 0xDB, 0xAF, 0x4F, 0xF4, 0xC6,
    0xAB, 0xD8, 0x71, 0xCC, 0x22, 0x04, 0x51, 0xD2,
    0xEA, 0x26, 0x48, 0x84, 0x6C, 0x77, 0x57, 0xFB,
    0xAA, 0xC8, 0x2F, 0xE5, 0x1A, 0xD6, 0x4B, 0xEA
},....};
```

e.g.

```
  somenumber = blake2s_kat;
 char key[100] = some function to convert into char(somenumber);
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, with different solutions. Pick one.

Comment: You cannot portably convert this array to `char` type because it has members that hold values in the MSB. `char` has implementation defined signedness. Or maybe you are asking how to convert integers to strings?

Comment: What do you ask exactly? You cannot assign to arrays, and you can only initialize them with initialization lists. So `char key[100] = expression;` is a syntax error. You could assign to **pointers** that that is not what is asked here. Currently this question is *unclear*.

Comment: @user694733 well the question is equally bad for both languages here...

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is problematic, since two-dimensional array is not one-dimensional array.

If a cell is like a room
then a one-dimensional array is like a hallway populated with rooms
and a two-dimensional array is like a building populated with hallways
you can't just take a building and convert it into a hallway.

what you can do is to cast each sub-array of `uint8_t[]` to `char*`:

```
auto pointer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(blake2s_kat[SOME_INDEX]);
```

`blake2s_kat[SOME_INDEX]` **decayes** into `uint8_t*` which than can be casted to `char*`.

also, each sub array in your example seems to contain only 8x4 numbers, which is not 100. make sure that you consider the size of your arrays.

another possibility is to use `memcpy`:

```
char buffer[8x4]; 
memcpy(buffer, blake2s_kat[SOME_INDEX], 8x4);
```